# Order notation quirk

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, set-theory

> Is it true that $$O(n) = \bigcap \{ O(g) \mid g \in \omega(n) \}?$$

This appears to be a straighforward question about sets of functions, but on closer examination leads to some murky waters.
I would be interested either in a construction of a counterexample function which doesn't require a choice principle independent of ZF set theory, or a proof which avoids invoking such a principle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The identity is provable in ZF (or even in $\mathrm{RCA}_0^*$). The $\subseteq$ inclusion is trivial. For the $\supseteq$ inclusion,
let $f\notin O(n)$. Define an integer sequence $\{n_k:k\in\mathbb N\}$ by
$$n_k=\min\{n:|f(n)|\ge k^2(n+1)\}.$$
Note that $n_k$ is non-decreasing, $n_0=0$, and $\lim_kn_k=\infty$, thus $\mathbb N$ is the disjoint union of the intervals $[n_k,n_{k+1})$, and we can define a function $g$ by
$$g(n)=kn,\qquad n_k\le n<n_{k+1}.$$
Then $g\in\omega(n)$, but $f\notin O(g)$, as $|f(n_k)|\ge kg(n_k)$ for all $k$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! My handwaving argument was that for any finite subset $F$ of $\omega(n)$ there seems to be a function $f \in \bigcap \{O(g)\mid g \in F\} \setminus O(n)$, so by compactness there must exist a function $f \in \bigcap \{O(g)\mid g \in \omega(n)\} \setminus O(n)$. I am probably assuming that these are all first-order sentences and missed something in there which is not first-order expressible.

Comment: Are you talking about expressibility in models of ZF? Your compactness argument only ensures that any model $M$ has an *elementary extension* $M'$ with $f\in M'$ such that $M'\models f\notin O(n)$ and $M'\models f\in O(g)$ for each $g\in M$ such that $M\models g\in\omega(n)$. However, there will be new functions $g\in M'\smallsetminus M$ such that $M'\models g\in\omega(n)$, and for these, $M'\models f\in O(g)$ may fail.

Comment: I overlooked that the new functions in the elementary extension may fail to dominate $f$; thank you for the clear exposition.